# How to send a dill byte object to restful api

Tags: python, flask, blob, flask-restful, dill

I am using flask restful on the server and need to use dill in order to dump a function to a binary and send it to the server

I am using this code to create the request

```
import inspect
import dill
import requests

def f():
    a = 1
    v = 2
    return 1

b = dill.dumps(f, protocol=None)

requests.post("http://localhost:5000/server", data={"func": b})
```

and using this code on the server

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from flask import app
from flask import Flask
import dill

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class S(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument("func", type=bytes, location="form")
        try:
            args = parser.parse_args()
            print(dill.loads(args["func"])())
            print(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print(2)
api.add_resource(S, '/server')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

I keep geting errors about request that the server could not understand, 
I tried marking the type as bytes, bytearray, str
I tried sending it in data, json and params 
all without any luck.

What am i missing here?

Comment: are you intent to send a python code to server?

Comment: `data` argument supposed to contain `dict` with key/value **str** pairs. [Read the docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Comment: A warning: `pickle` is already not safe with untrusted input; `dill` is `pickle` on steroids (as you no doubt intend, since pickling the actual function, rather than just the qualified name, is a feature of `dill` that `pickle` lacks). If you expose this API on the web, you're *asking* to be hacked.

Comment: Not to worry, we are not running it on our server.